# Delphi: How to catch TStreamWriter Disk full error?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, filestream, writer

I wonder, why this code does not catch a 'Disk Full' error like it should?

This is important because the user may lose their data if they do not notice that the saving failed.

I don't get this...

```pascal
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
  n : integer;
begin
Writer := TStreamWriter.Create('MyUTF8Text.txt', false, TEncoding.UTF8);
  Try //Finally
    Try //Except
      
      for n := 1 to 1000 do
      begin
        Writer.WriteLine('Testing text writing to the UTF-8 file.');
      end;
    Except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage('Exception Class name: ' + E.ClassName);
        ShowMessage('Exception Message: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end; // except
  Finally
    Writer.Free(); 
  End; //finally
end;
```

"BTW. 'Writer might not be initialized' warning, is it serious really?"

Edit: There was this warning because TStreamWriter.Create was after TRY.
Thanks for your advice I corrected that line of code to the correct location before(!) the TRY.

Comment: If TStreamWriter's constructor raise an exception, Writer won't be initialized. So yeah, this is serious. The idiomatic way of doing it is creating the object before the `try`

Comment: your try...finally block is pointless when you embed a try...except block. You want it the other way around... And like Ken pointed out, you want to create an object before the start of a try block.

Comment: Ken is very right. `Writer` is a local variable of a non-managed type, hence not initialised. IOW, it is initially a random pointer. If `TStreamWriter.Create(...)` raises an exception, which it not unlikely, the destructor will run automatically and dispose of the semi-created stream writer. Because of the exception, `Writer` will not be assigned a pointer to an object (there is no new object!) for execution will move to `except` and then `finally`, and so you do `Writer.Free` on a random ptr `Writer`. That's very bad. ALWAYS use the idiom `X := TX.Create; try {use X} finally X.Free; end`.

Comment: Anyhow, is it `TStreamWriter.Create` that raises the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
procedure WriteStream;
var
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
  fs: TFileStream;
  s: String;
  n, bytesWritten : integer;
begin
  bytesWritten := 0;
  fs := TFileStream.Create('MyUTF8Text.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    //avoid warning by initiaizing before try
    Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(fs);
    try //Finally
      try //Except
        for n := 1 to 10 do
        begin
          s := 'Testing text writing to the UTF-8 file.'  + '#13#10';
          //keep count of bytes written
          bytesWritten := bytesWritten + TEncoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s);
          Writer.Write(s);
        end;
        Writer.Flush;
        Writer.Close;
        //Check stream size to make sure all bytes written
        if bytesWritten <> Writer.BaseStream.Size then
          raise Exception.Create(String.Format('Expected %d bytes, wrote %d', [Writer.BaseStream.Size, bytesWritten]));
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          Showmessage('Exception Class name: ' + E.ClassName);
          Showmessage('Exception Message: ' + E.Message);
        end;
      end; // except
    finally
      Writer.Free; // Will only free if it has been constructed
    end; //finally
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Small nitpick - `TEncoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s)` can be `Writer.Encoding.GetByteCoint(s)`. This way, if you ever decide to change the `TEncoding` used, you only have to update 1 line of code (the constructor) instead of 2 lines.

Comment: IPlease note that this solution will not catch disk full problem (ie if TFilestream.Create fails)...

Comment: `'#13#10'` should probably be `#13#10`. You don't need the `+` operator.

Comment: Thansk for your answers. *Tav*, your code works ok, thanks!  However, I hoped that the solution would have been even simpler. Similar to saving Memo text to a UTF-8 file as follows:
  var  myEncoding : TEncoding; 
begin 
myEncoding := TEncoding.UTF8; 
try 
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('myUTF8file.txt', myEncoding); 
except 
on E: Exception do 
begin Showmessage('Exception Class name: ' + E.ClassName); // This gives: "EWriteError" 
Showmessage('Exception Message: ' + E.Message); // This gives: "Stream Write Error" not Disk Full - 112 'Not enough room' error...
end; 
end; // except
end;

Comment: Yes, Tav's code offers a solution, but the main problem still exists: how to catch a disk full error? Or is stream I/O handling completely different from traditional file management?